# Is there an API to check if column name is SQL Keyword Java

Tags: java, sql

So, I have a string and I need to know if there is an API to check if the name is an SQL Keyword? Ex:

```
<api>.isKeyWord("SELECT") -> true
<api>.isKeyWord("Person") -> false
```

Comment: I don't think so, mainly because SQL and Java are not the same language. And most databases have a slightly different SQL dialect.

Comment: You can find a list of keyword though. Just build a map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use [DatabaseMetaData.getSQLKeywords()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getSQLKeywords%28%29).  You would of course need to combine this with a static list of the SQL 2003 keywords (which i'm sure is readily available somewhere).  To be safe, i would treat all of these words as case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

you can self define a dictionary of SQL words and check against the SQL query with a string spl